# MySql take backup of recently updated/inserted data

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I have database of **size 500mb**, to take backup it is taking huge time to take full dump file, I just want to know is there any way we can take backup queries for date between from and to date-times, so that I can take back in particular time interval.

I know we can take whole db backup using

```
`$ > mysqldump -u username -p db_name > path/file.sql`
```

Thanks in advance :)

any suggestions accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--where` option for mysqldump to take a subset of rows. For example:

```
mysqldump --where "updated_at > '2020-06-14 00:00:00'" ...other options...
```

However, this will add that WHERE condition to each table it dumps. So you must have an `updated_at` column in every table. MySQL does not require such a column to exist, so this is up to you and your table design conventions.

Another method is to use the binary log. You can dump the contents of the binary log as a series of SQL statements that reproduce the incremental changes.

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime "2020-06-14 00:00:00" ...other options...
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html for full documentation on using this command.

Comment: sure @bill karwin, will take a look, thanks a lot :)